# My AJAX LiveDate Object

Tags: javascript, performance, object-oriented, datetime, ajax

The `LiveDate` object displays the live current date and has a `sendAjaxRequest()` function dependency to send the AJAX requests.

I'd like to have a full review of any aspects of my code:

- OOP
- **Readability**
- Performance
- Usability
- JS conventions
- Error handling

Any *other* suggestions for improvement are always welcome!

**sendAjaxRequest.js**

```
'use strict';

function sendAjaxRequest(url, callback, postData) {
    var XHR_FACTORIES = [
        function () { return new XMLHttpRequest(); },
        function () { return new ActiveXObject('Msxml3.XMLHTTP'); },
        function () { return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0'); },
        function () { return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0'); },
        function () { return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP'); },
        function () { return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP'); }
    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < XHR_FACTORIES.length; i++) {
        try {
            var xhr = XHR_FACTORIES[i]();
        } catch (e) {
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    if (typeof xhr === 'undefined') {
        throw {
            name: 'AjaxSupportException',
            context: 'Trying to instantiate an XMLHttpRequest object from one of the predefined factories.',
            problem: 'No XMLHttpRequest object available for the current client.',
            solution: 'Use a major client that does support AJAX.',
            toString: function () { return this.name; }
        };
    }

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState !== 4) {
            return;
        }

        callback.apply(xhr);
    }

    xhr.open(postData ? 'POST' : 'GET', url);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('User-Agent', 'XMLHTTP/1.0'); // Raises a Chrome refusal notice.

    if (postData) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    }

    xhr.send();
};
```

**LiveDate.js**

```
'use strict';

function LiveDate(timeUrl, element, options) {
    if (typeof sendAjaxRequest !== 'function') {
        throw {
            name: 'DependencyException',
            context: 'Checking the availability of the sendAjaxRequest function.',
            problem: 'The function is not available.',
            solution: 'Load / include the sendAjaxRequest function.',
            toString: function () { return this.name; }
        };
    }

    // Required arguments.
    this.timeUrl = timeUrl;
    this.element = element;

    // Optional arguments.
    this.format = options.format || 'l j F Y - H:i:s';
    this.offset = options.offset || 0;

    this.weekdayNames = {};
    this.monthNames = {};

    this.weekdayNames.long = options.weekdayNames.long || [
        'Sunday',
        'Monday',
        'Tuesday',
        'Wednesday',
        'Thursday',
        'Friday',
        'Saturday'
    ];

    this.weekdayNames.short = options.weekdayNames.short || [
        'Sun',
        'Mon',
        'Tue',
        'Wed',
        'Thu',
        'Fri',
        'Sat'
    ];

    this.monthNames.long = options.monthNames.long || [
        'January',
        'February',
        'March',
        'April',
        'May',
        'June',
        'July',
        'August',
        'September',
        'October',
        'November',
        'December'
    ];

   this.monthNames.short = options.monthNames.short || [
        'Jan',
        'Feb',
        'Mar',
        'Apr',
        'May',
        'Jun',
        'Jul',
        'Aug',
        'Sep',
        'Oct',
        'Nov',
        'Dec'
    ];

    this._date; //private

    this.start();
}

LiveDate.prototype = {
    start: function () {
        var self = this;

        sendAjaxRequest(this.timeUrl + '?nocache=' + Math.random(), function () {
            var requestTime = new Date().getTime(),
                previousTime = new Date().getTime(),
                serverTime = parseInt(this.responseText);

            if (this.status !== 200) {
                self.element.innerHTML = '<span style="color: red;"><b>Live Date Error</b></span>';

                throw {
                    name: 'AjaxRequestException',
                    context: 'Sending an AJAX request to: ' + this.timeUrl + '.',
                    problem: 'HTTP ' + this.status + ' was returned but expected HTTP 200.',
                    solution: 'Double check the URL and make sure it\'s reachable.',
                    toString: function () { return this.name; }
                };
            }

            self.tickIntervalId = setInterval(function tick() {
                var currentTime = new Date().getTime();

                // Detecting client's system date changes to keep ours unaffected.
                // Interval delay increment taken into account as well (+500 ms).
                if ((currentTime - previousTime) < 0 || (currentTime - previousTime) >= 1500) {
                    self.stop();

                    // Introducing a delay particularly for PC's that've just been awoken to
                    // try and prevent an AjaxRequestException from being thrown due to their
                    // Internet connection not being reinitialized yet.
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        self.start();
                    }, 10000);

                    return;
                }

                self._date = new Date(serverTime + currentTime - requestTime + self.offset);

                self.element.innerHTML = self.formatAs(self.format);

                previousTime = currentTime;

                return tick;
            }(), 200);
        });
    },

    formatAs: function (format) {
        var self = this;

        var dateFormatter = {
            // Day
            // A full textual representation of the day of the week, e.g. Monday.
            l: function () { return self.weekdayNames.long[self._date.getUTCDay()]; },

            //Month
            // A full textual representation of a month, e.g. January.
            F: function () { return self.monthNames.long[self._date.getUTCMonth()]; },
            // Day of the month without leading zeros.
            j: function () { return self._date.getUTCDate(); },

            // Year
            // A full numeric representation of a year, e.g. 2015.
            Y: function () { return self._date.getUTCFullYear(); },

            // Time
            // 24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros.
            H: function () { return ('0' + self._date.getUTCHours()).slice(-2); },
            // Minutes with leading zeros.
            i: function () { return ('0' + self._date.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2); },
            // Seconds with leading zeros.
            s: function () { return ('0' + self._date.getUTCSeconds()).slice(-2); }

            // More formatting methods to be added in the future.
        };

        return format.replace(/(\\?)([a-z])/gi, function (match, isEscaped, char) {
            return !isEscaped && dateFormatter[char] ? dateFormatter[char]() : char;
        });
    },

    getTime: function () {
        return this._date.getTime();
    },

    stop: function () {
        clearInterval(this.tickIntervalId);

        this.tickIntervalId = null;
    }
};
```

**Example**

```
new LiveDate('time.php', document.getElementById('date'), {
    format: 'l j F Y - <\\b>H:i:s</\\b>',
    offset: 7200000, // Paris
    weekdayNames: {
        long: [
            'dimanche',
            'lundi',
            'mardi',
            'mercredi',
            'jeudi',
            'vendredi',
            'samedi'
        ]
    },
    monthNames: {
        long: [
            'janvier',
            'fèvrier',
            'mars',
            'avril',
            'mai',
            'juin',
            'juillet',
            'août',
            'septembre',
            'octobre',
            'novembre',
            'décembre'
        ]
    }
});
```

Comment: You must define the good method outside of your function `sendAjaxRequest` once and for all.

Comment: Most browsers either support `XmlHttpRequest` (the majority) or `new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")` (the minority (IE)) - you don't really need to support anything else.

Comment: Are you sure that the `Msxml3.XMLHTTP` progID exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `XHR_FACTORIES` as array of anonymous functions, which is a bad practice in itself. You can't reliably test these functions as your index will change any time you update your array. A better way would be something like:

```
var XHR_FACTORIES = [
    emptyRequest = function () { return new XMLHttpRequest(); },
    Msxml3Request = ...,
       ...
]
```

Then you can still loop over all object properties or specific ones. [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) is a great library for those tasks to shorten your code.

---

Your code is sensitive to how `new ActiveXObject` behaves. You seem to expect error if it fails but what if silently returns `undefined` or `null` without failing? It would go through another loop and overwrite the previous setting.

I would also encapsulate the loop inside a function that I can both test and debug.

Also I would make sure that function returns a unique failure result, not dependent on the browser.

---

You are using the verbose raw JS way to handle XHR, whereas libraries like `jQuery` would do a lot of heavy lifting for you. If for any reason, you prefer not to use third party libraries here, you can still imitate `jQuery`'s encapsulation architecture, so later you (or whoever will use your code) will be able to quickly change to `jQuery`.

---

Hardcoded "magic" numbers like `10000`. Anything other than `0`, `1`, `null`, `undefined`, `[]`, `""` is considered "magic constants" that are better not to leave hardcoded. Give them meaningful names instead for both testability and readability.

---

The last argument `200` inside `setInterval` is too far away down, making the code hard to read. It is better to define your `tick` function separately, and use it a short line inside `setInterval`.

Also executing your function inside `setInterval` is a recipe for errors and hard reading.

---

Not sure what is the purpose of this declaration:

```
this._date; //private
```

This property is either being created when it is defined, or else, the calls like `this._date.getTime()` will still fail. You may want to check for existence of that property instead when calling it.

---

You are re-defining `LiveDate.prototype`, which is a bad practice. It will break the `prototype` chain, forget all your previous `prototype` properties and can lead to unintended effects if using `.constructor` (which isn't good idea too unless you know what you are doing). It is better to specify individual properties of it.